# Plotting a function of vectors and sample points

Tags: plotting, vector, constraint

I need to plot a function of vectors.
\begin{equation}
2y\vec{r}\cdot\vec{x}+2y^2+\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x}=1.
\end{equation}
This is actually an equation of constraint. Given $\vec{r}$, with $|\vec{r}|\leq1$, I want to see the possible values of $y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\vec{x}$. How do I go about doing it? I know I can make $\vec{r}=r_x\hat{i}$ and solve for the surface. But I'll have to do it for each component. How can I generate sample points? Thanks for any help.

Comment: So, what kind of plot do you want? That seems like a lot of degrees of freedom, more than you can have in a simple visualization. And how are you expecting to combine scalars and vectors into the same plot? This problem is *severely* under-defined, and it seems like it's not even about the computing software *Mathematica*. Please update your post with more information.

Comment: I've updated the problem. I found out that I can simplify it more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps, something like:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 1}}, Panel@Row[
   {LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt, (pt = If[Norm[#, 2] < 1, #, Normalize[#, Norm[#, 2] &]]) &], 
    RegionPlot[Norm[{x, y}, 2] <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
     Frame -> False, Axes -> True, Epilog -> {PointSize[.05], Point[Dynamic[pt]]}, 
     ImageSize -> 300, PlotLabel -> Dynamic[Style["r = " <> ToString[pt], 20]]], 
     Appearance -> None], 
   Dynamic@ContourPlot3D[2 y^2 + 2 y Dot[pt, {w, z}] + Dot[ {w, z}, {w, z}] == 
      1, {y, -3/2, 3/2}, {w, -3/2, 3/2}, {z, -3/2, 3/2}, 
     ImageSize -> 400, PlotLabel -> Style["{y, x1, x2}", 20], 
     AxesLabel -> {"y", "x1", "x2"}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I think that it must be modified. For a 1-D $\vec{r}$, then I get a surface. But for a 2-D $\vec{r}$, then it should be a hypersurface, which is not visualizable. There should be 3 variables for $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x}$. Just glad to know that it can be done. I'm new to mathematica. Just curious, can I have a 3D plot on the left side as well?  Thanks.